# How do I use "and" condition in JSON schema?

Tags: json, if-statement, schema

I want to check 2 conditions using if statement in JSON schema

if( "field1" = "A")  and ("field2" ="B" )
then
required:["field3"]

Is it possible to implement the above? How do I achieve this?

I'm not sure how does the consequent if works?

Comment: In which language, are you trying to implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.